# Netty Websocket SSL client not working after a successful handshake

Tags: ssl, websocket, netty

I want to create a secure websocket client-server communication using Netty framework. I looked at the netty examples and there is an example with websocket ssl server: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

and there is also another example with websocket client, but without ssl: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/client

So I've put the SslHandler as the first hander in the ChannelPipelinehandle as suggested here: [How can use netty websocket client with wss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082396/how-can-use-netty-websocket-client-with-wss/)

But it still does not work. Client successfully connects to server (handshake succeeds), but then when client sends a message to server (for example PingWebSocketFrame or any other WebSocketFrame) nothing happens. Server does not receive any message.

Do you have an idea what might be wrong?

EDIT: I use 4.0.0.CR5 and to be exact, server always receives something, but only first SSLHandler. Next handler in the pipeline (HttpRequestDecoder) then receives a message only sometimes, and when it does, it creates DefaultHttpRequest with this failure:

decodeResult: failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: |￳LZSﾺ

Those weird characters should probably represent an HTTP version, but it looks like SSLHandler did not decode them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (you can see the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636249/netty-and-ssl-websocket-client)).

The sample code on the client uses the channel.write() method, which seems not to forward the messages to the Websocket ssl server. By using the channel.writeAndFlush() instead, messages are correctly sent to the server.

All these were tested using the netty 4.0.9.Final version