# Netty and SSL websocket client

Tags: ssl, websocket, netty

I'm struggling with Netty 4.0.8 Websocket client example and SSL and I can't seem to be able to send data to the Netty SSL websocket server example. Although there have been many posts around this issue, (I went through all, I believe), and the most common suggestion is to just add an sslHandler  to the beginning of the pipeline, it doesn't work. Handshake seems to be successful as it is also indicated to a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131461/netty-websocket-ssl-client-not-working-after-a-successful-handshake).

I remember being in the same situation with version 4.0.0, but I somehow managed to get it working. However, things (and API) changed when I upgraded to 4.0.8.

Can the Netty developers add a working Websocket SSL client example to the examples? Many people struggle with this issue and that would be useful. Maybe the solution is just too simple, but an example would clear things. Again, sorry for reposting a question that might be already there, but the relevant question has also been unanswered and my reputation is just too low to add a comment to other relevant questions :)

Comment: Please open an issue as "feature request" so we can add it as soon as we have the cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution to my own question. The sample code on the client uses the channel.write() method, which seems not to send the messages to the Websocket ssl server. By using the channel.writeAndFlush() instead, messages are correctly sent to the server.

Comment: The write() method will send the message once its buffer is full. The writeAndFlush() method immediately sends the message (write to buffer, then flush the buffer).